# Banco de Dados - MySQL - Relacionamento entre tabelas / INNER, LEFT, RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, relacionamento, inner-join

Estou fazendo um banco de dados usando a workbench do MySQL e estou precisando de um breve auxilio.
Eu tenho 6 entidades no total. tb_pessoas que está relacionada a outras duas entidades tb_clientes e tb_adm(pois o usuário cadastrado poderá ser um cliente ou adm). A tb_clientes está relacionada a tb_agendar(pois o cliente agenda a data da consulta) e a tb_adm está relacionada a tb_funcionarios e a tb_servicos(pois só o adm pode cadastrar funcionários e servicos).
Eu consegui pegar o nome do cliente e a data da consulta porém, eu preciso também pegar o servico que ele vai fazer, o preco que ele vai pagar  e do nome do funcionário que vai atender o cliente.
Segue um anexo para visualizar melhor o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não publique código como imagem, leia o [Manual e como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132), o código deve ser sempre publicado como texto para facilitar a operacionalização de quem vai responder.

Comment: Cada JOIN deve ter sua própria cláusula ON. A sua cláusula ON está errada.

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que o que deseja é:

```
SELECT *    FROM tb_pessoas 
            INNER JOIN tb_clientes ON tb_pessoas.idpessoa = tb_clientes.idpessoa
            INNER JOIN tb_agendar ON tb_clientes.idcliente = tb_agendar.idcliente
            INNER JOIN tb_adm ON tb_pessoas.idpessoa = tb_adm.idpessoa
            INNER JOIN tb_funcionarios ON tb_adm.idadm = tb_funcionarios.idadm
            INNER JOIN tb_servicos ON tb_adm.idadm = tb_servicos.idadm;
```

Substitua o `*` pelos campos que desejar, lembrando de qualifica-los quando necessário.